# Qt for Android Error: Target id 'android--1' is not valid

Tags: android, c++, qt

I try to create a Qt application for desktop and android platforms. All parameters in Tools->Options->Android are correct.

[Qt Android settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n3C4.png)

When I try to build my application, I get an error:

```
Error: Target id 'android--1' is not valid. Use 'android.bat list targets' to get the target ids.
```

But I have several platforms installed (android-10, 15, 19, 23). Also, I have found some info on [the same issue issue](https://forum.qt.io/topic/55096/error-target-id-android-1-is-not-valid), but it have not helped me.

I use:

- Windows 7 x64
- Qt Creator 3.6.0 Based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)
- Qt 5.5.1

Has somebody encountered with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the project
2. Open ProjectName.pro.user file with notepad
3. Find value with key: "BuildTargetSdk"
4. Change 'android--1' to Something like 'android-16' or other version
5. Save the file and open the project again
   may be needed to repeat steps again